# Challenging Limit Question

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{4n} \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{rx}{n} \right)}{\sqrt{n^2 x^2 + r x^3} + \sqrt{n^2 x^2 + (r - 1)x^3}} \right)
$$
I tried making $r/n$'s, so I could substitute them for a new variable $y$ to convert the summation into an integral, but it didnt work.

Comment: Rightclick how other people have written things, choose 'Show Math As -> Tex Commands'.  Visit [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typing MathJax here.

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: $$ S_n(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{4n} \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{rx}{n} \right)}{\sqrt{n^2 x^2 + r x^3} + \sqrt{n^2 x^2 + (r - 1)x^3}}> \sum_{r=1}^{4n} \frac{\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)}{\sqrt{n^2 x^2 + 4n x^3} + \sqrt{n^2 x^2 + (4n - 1)x^3}}$$
$$=\frac{4n\left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)}{\sqrt{n^2 x^2 + 4n x^3} + \sqrt{n^2 x^2 + (4n - 1)x^3}}\to\frac2x\,\text{at}\,n\to\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(x)\right)=\infty$$

Comment: @JMoravitz thank's i'll keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku Nothing much really, I took the $x$'s out of the square root and cancelled them, same for $n$ to get $r/n$ in the numerator, and $r/n^2$ in the denominator, the main motivation to convert the summation into an integral, by substituing $r/n$ as $y$ and $1/n$ as $dy$.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I don't think there is a problem with your approach, but I am afraid the answer given is $2$.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I tried, but couldn't write it in latex, someone did that for me, thanks!